# node.js EPIPE exception on child_process.spawn

Tags: node.js, spawn, epipe

I'm using `node.js v0.6.10` although I've got the same issue on `0.6.7`.  Basically I run a child process using `spawn` that starts another node.js process, and communicates over `stdout` and `stdin`  Here are the two scripts:

**parent (`cli.js`)**:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

var doSpawn = function(callback){
  var child = spawn('child.js');

  child.on('exit', function(code){
    console.log("Child exited with code " + code);
  });

  child.stdin.write("ping");
  child.stdin.end();
};


doSpawn();

setTimeout(function(){}, 10000);
```

**`child.js`**

```
var run = function(){
  process.stdout.on('drain', function(){
    process.exit(0);
  });

  process.stdout.write(stdout);
};

var stdin = process.stdin;

stdin.resume();
stdin.setEncoding("utf8");

var stdout = '';

stdin.on('data', function(data){
  stdout += data;
});

stdin.on('end', run);
```

And then when I run `node cli.js`:

```
$ node cli.js 

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at errnoException (net.js:642:11)
    at Object.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:480:18)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I created a github repo that you can pull down and run: https://github.com/rubymaverick/nodejs-epipe-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run another node process *child_process.fork()* is recommended
http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_processes.html#child_process.fork

Code with changes:

```
var cp = require("child_process");

var doSpawn = function(callback){
  var child = cp.fork('child.js');

  child.on('exit', function(code){
    console.log("Child exited with code " + code);
  });

  child.stdin.write("ping");
  child.stdin.end();
};


doSpawn();

setTimeout(function(){}, 10000);
```